# FFmpeg ass filter doesn't use font i choose

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

I created an .ass file with specified font (SF Pro Semibold) and wanted to merge with a video.

.ass file:

```bash
[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: videoaltyazi,SF Pro Semibold,75.0,&H00CDCDCD,&H0000FFFF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100.0,0.0,0,3,10.5,3.0,2,10,10,120,1
```

FFmpeg can actually detect the font either specifying the location of font or not.

```bash
PS > ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf ass=sub.ass:fontsdir=".\subtitle\SF-Pro-Display-Semibold.otf" output.mp4
ffmpeg version 6.0-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
...
[Parsed_ass_0 @ 000001c267a2d180] libass API version: 0x1700000
[Parsed_ass_0 @ 000001c267a2d180] libass source: commit: 0.17.0-39-g04a208d5d200360d2ac75f8f6cfc43dd58dd9225
[Parsed_ass_0 @ 000001c267a2d180] Shaper: FriBidi 1.0.12 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 7.0.1 (COMPLEX)
[Parsed_ass_0 @ 000001c267a2d180] Using font provider directwrite (with GDI)
[Parsed_ass_0 @ 000001c267a2d180] Added subtitle file: 'sub.ass' (2 styles, 1 events)
...
[Parsed_ass_0 @ 000001c267a2d180] fontselect: (SF Pro Semibold, 400, 0) -> SFPro-Semibold, 0, SFPro-Semibold
```

But subtitle font of output video is not Sf Pro Semibold. It's just look like SF Pro.

When I drag subtitle file to original video in MPC-HC, subtitle just look like what I want. I edited a screenshot in ShareX and used font I guess. Here is the comparison:

[image]

How can I use the font I want?